# Особенности WAP

Tags: php, mysql, wap

Есть мысль написать мобильный сайт знакомств на **PHP MySQL**. Расскажите насчет особенности WAP, какие нужно учитывать параметры (браузеров, ось [обязательно-необязательно]) при разработке, расширение **должно** быть wml? Мне в принципе хватает эти возможностей:

1. Регистрация
2. Загрузка фото, возможно и альбомчик.
3. Отправка смс (если забыл пароль-логин), если возможно.
4. Javascript (jQuery) поддерживается ли? Слыхал, что есть специальный wmlscript вместо js.

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того что телефонов сейчас дофига и чучуть. Современные телефоны поддерживают html не хуже броузеров, поэтому для них желательно отдавать html, а для старых телефонов - WML. В каждом телефоне свои особенности. Для начала нужно составить базу устройств в которых вписаны характеристики этих устройств, таких как разрешение экрана, 
поддержку html / wml ит.д. Впринципе есть готовые решения - WURFL

1. Ничем не отличается от обычного сайта, просто маркап другой (wml например)
2. Загрузку фото можно сделать через ММС (в телефонах есть возможность отправлять не только на номер но и на email)
3. В ВМЛ девайсах лучше от скриптов отказатся вообще.
4. javascript лучше пихать в последние модели телефонов на базе Андроид, iOS, BlackBerry.. jQuery лучше не использовать. Для мобильных телефонов есть мобильная версиЯ jquery - [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Вообще говоря, если вы спрашиваете про регистрацию - то придется вам тяжко что бы осилить всё это.